# Inicializar con una cantidad variable de los mismos elementos en un array

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero llenar una cantidad, por ejemplo 9 elementos del array con el valor de 0

```
let resultados = [];
    resultados[0] = 0;
    resultados[1] = 0;
    resultados[2] = 0;
    resultados[3] = 0;
    resultados[4] = 0;
    resultados[5] = 0;
    resultados[6] = 0;
    resultados[7] = 0;
    resultados[8] = 0;
```

quiero generalizarlo para llenar n elementos en el array, existe alguna funcion propia de js para hacer esto? o debo hacerlo con un ciclo para llenarlo?

Comment: La forma mas corta de realizar esto me parece es: let resultados = new Array(9);
resultados.fill(0, 0, resultados.length);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma es como lo realizas, inicializar todos los elementos con el valor 0.

Pero si haz creado un array e independientemente de la cantidad de elementos que contenga tu array, puedes realizar un bucle para modificar el valor de todos sus elementos:

```
for( i=0; i< resultados.length; i++){
   resultados[i] = 0;
}
```

de esta forma todos los elementos en tu array tendrían el valor de `0`.

---

**Si ya tienes creado tu Array y deseas inicializar sus valores**, otra forma es utilizar el método [fill(valor, inicio, final)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/fill)

> - valor Valor con el que se va rellenar el arreglo.
> - inicio Índice inicial, por defecto es 0.
> - final Índice final, por defecto es this.length.

```
resultados.fill(0, 0, resultados.length)
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var resultados = myArray.fill(0, 0, 9)
 
for(i = 0;i<resultados.length;i++){   
 console.log("valor en indice ["+i+"] " + resultados[i])  
}
```

---

**Si deseas crear inicialmente tu array conteniendo valores 0**, puedes usar el mismo método [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/fill) de esta forma:

```js
//Crea array con nueve elementos y asigna valor 0
var resultados = new Array(9).fill(0);

//verifica valores de elementos en array    
for(i = 0;i<resultados.length;i++){   
 console.log("valor en indice ["+i+"] " + resultados[i])  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

La forma más fácil para mi es la siguiente:

```js
var len = ~~(Math.random() * 28);
console.log(`Array length will be ${len}`);
var array = new Array(len).fill(0);
console.log(array);
```

Donde `len` es la longitud de tu arreglo y el `0` es el valor por defecto que deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Esto tal vez te sirva:

```
let resultados =new Array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Es una forma de asignar los valores al momento de crearlo.

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner código, debes explicarlo

Comment: sigue siendo estatico, no hay algo como .fill(elementos, valores) ?

Answer (score 1):

En javascript, si a una función le asignas 10 parámetros de los cuales solo 4 van con valor y estos los vas a agregar a un arreglo, si la función es única los agregara 10 valores de los cuales 4 van con valor, pero esto es un método donde el arreglo es estático.

```js
function llenarArray(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10) {
  let resultados = new Array(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10);
  return resultados;
}

console.log(llenarArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toString());
console.log(llenarArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, null, null, null, null).toString());
```

Si lo que deseas es un array dinámico, puedes optar por ingresar los valores al igual que una lista, lo cual es necesario un ciclo ya sea dentro de la función o un ciclo llamando a la función, esta última opción es la más viable ya que tu función sólo ingresa un valor y desde donde llamas a la función controlas el tamaño del arreglo.

```js
var array = [];

function llenarArray(valor) {
  array.push(valor)
}
llenarArray("1");
llenarArray("2");
llenarArray("3");
llenarArray("4");
console.log(array.toString())
```

Desde fuera de la función llenando el arreglo.

```js
var array = [],
  size = 5;

function llenarArray(valor) {
  array.push(valor)
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  llenarArray(i * 10);
}
console.log(array.toString())
```

**ECMASCRIPT 6**

Uno de los cambios con los que más se gana en comodidad, la posibilidad de definir un número indeterminado de parámetros en instrucciones de asignación, ya sea como parámetro de una función o como definición de una variable.

```js
function llenarArray(...candidates) { // candidates contains the rest of arguments passed
  let array = [...candidates]
  return array;
}

let result = llenarArray("banana", "apple","kiwi");

console.log(result); // ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "watermelon", "strawberry"]
```